# Ionic 2 Native Camera - picture not displayed

Tags: angular, ionic2

like written in the title, after taking the picture with the camera native function, the picture isn't displayed.

I'm trying on Android 5.0
Let me know if you want/need any other informations.

There is the code :
I tried to display the picture with "[src]" & "src", I also tried the `"src="{{ base64Image }}""` same result...
[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cordova-plugin-camera to display image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42785838/using-cordova-plugin-camera-to-display-image)

Comment: src="{{base64Image}}" /> works fine for me in my project.. Try the FILE_URI version without livereload maybe.. DATA_URL so heavy.

Comment: I tried but the result is still the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the answer for me, it works now.

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/using-camera-native-picture-isnt-displayed/83780

Thanks for your help & time ! EnjoyCoding !

:)

Answer (score 0):

Remove `data: image/jpeg;base64,`

Keep `this.base64image = ""+imagedata;`

It's working...

Here is my code:

```
openCamera() {

    var options = {
        quality: 100,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        allowEdit: false,
        // encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
        // targetWidth: 250,
        // targetHeight: 250,
        saveToPhotoAlbum: false,
        correctOrientation: false,
        cameraDirection: Camera.Direction.FRONT
    };

    Camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this._zone.run(() => {
            this.base64Image = imageData;
            //"data:image/jpeg;base64," +
        });
    }, (error) => {
        console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

Comment: By removing the **data:image/jpeg;base64,** it changes nothing.
I tried with your code, nothing more..

Comment: Hi Petalomine,

Can you replace your method and add following code

`import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';`

`constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
        private _zone: NgZone,
        public navParams: NavParams) {}`


One more try...

Comment: ion-card-content still blank.. but thanks trying to help me