# Unable to display image using FILE_URI

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am using cordova plugin camera to display image , if destinationType is DATA_URL it works fine

.ts:

```
getPic(){
 const options: CameraOptions = {
   quality: 100,
   sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM,
   destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI
  }

 this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 this.success = 'getting image is successful';
 this.Image = imageData;
 }, (err) => {
  this.err = err;
});
}
```

html:

```
<button ion-button primary (click)="getPic()">get picture</button>

<img src="{{Image}}" />
 <p>this is image: {{Image}}</p>  //Output -> content://media/external/images/media/1022
 <p>{{success}}</p>
 <p>{{err}}</p>
```

I have also added this to index.html but still not working `<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">`

Comment: also try http://stackoverflow.com/a/42796752/4826457

Comment: sorry , yes it worked using DomSanitizer , thanx suraj